# String index out of range error when trying to read data from a text file

Tags: string, indexing

I'm trying to figure out why this code is returning a string index out of range error. I'm working on a larger project and trying to break it down into modules. The code and contents of the text file are below. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!
Sean

```
file='figures.txt'
figures_file=open(file,'r')
leader_names_list=[]
leader_scores_list=[]
for line in figures_file:

    name=''
    score=''
    index=0
    while (line[index] != ','):
        name=name+line[index]
        index=index+1
    index=index+1
    while line[index] != '\n':
        score=score+line[index]
        index=index+1
    leader_names_list.append(name)
    leader_scores_list.append(score)

print (leader_names_list)
print (leader_scores_list)
figures_file.close()
```

text file contents
sean,50
veronica,40
nicholas,30

Comment: The  specific line that is returning an error is (while line[index] != '\n'

Answer (score 0):

Add additional condition that `index` couldn't be greater than length of a string:

```
while index < len(line) and line[index] != ',':
    ...
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening, because the last line in the file has not a `\n` so the second loop does not stop at the end of `nicholas,30` because there is not a new line char there and try to keep looking for the next position, after the increment of `index` inside the loop, and that does not exist so when trying to do `while line[index]....` throw you the error.

If you have an empty line at the end of the file, there is a `\n` after `nicholas,30`, then the error will happen at the next line. That's why checking that index never should be greater than line length as @roddar92 suggested you fix it. But I guess you will need that check-in both loops.